# Magento 2: How to get Order Item's Direct Without Inner Loop

Tags: magento2, orders, collection, optimization, items

I have below code for fetching Order's which has payment method "Paypal Express"

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection')
                ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.payment_method', 'paypal_express')
                ->addFieldToFilter('sop.method', 'paypal_express');

        $orderCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['si' => 'sales_order_item'], "main_table.entity_id = si.order_id");

        $orderCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['sop' => 'sales_order_payment'], "main_table.entity_id = sop.entity_id");

        $orderCollection->load();
        //echo $orderCollection->printlogquery(true);

        foreach ($orderCollection as $orders) {
            echo $orderCustomerId = $orders->getCustomerId();
            echo "<pre>";
            echo $orderPaymentMethod = $orders->getPaymentMethod();
            echo "<pre>";
            echo $orderId = $orders->getId();
            echo "<pre>";
            echo $orderTransactionId = $orders->getLastTransId();
            echo "<pre>";
            $orderDetail = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
            $orderItems = $orderDetail->getAllItems();
            foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
                echo "<pre>";
                echo $itemPrice = $item->getPrice();
                echo "<pre>";
                echo $itemSku = $item->getSku();
            }
        }
```

For getting Order wise items, I have to Create Inner Foreach Loop, is there any way to remove it & access order items from 1st Foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following code into your order collection

```
$orderCollection->getSelect()
                ->join(
                    'sales_order_item',
                    'main_table.entity_id = sales_order_item.order_id',
                    array(
                        'sku'  => new \Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ",")'),
                        'price'  => new \Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_order_item`.price SEPARATOR ",")')
                    )
                );

$orderCollection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');
foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
    echo $order->getSku().' -> '.$order->getPrice().' <br/>';
}
```

Now you can get comma separated sku and price.

Comment: Excellent & Bravo. Bowing. Please try to help 2 Bounty Questions if can. Thanks